# Infer function parameter type from the generic on another parameter

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

I'm attempting to make a wrapper function for codegen'd Apollo lazy queries like so:

```
const { useGetPostsLazyQuery } from '../../schema';

function foo<T extends LazyQueryExecFunction<any, any>>(query: T, variables) {
  ...
}

foo(useGetPostsLazyQuery, {
  status: 'active'
});
```

I'd like the variables parameter to match the type of the query's variables (the 2nd generic on `LazyQueryExecFunction`). But the type of query inferred using the `T` generic, so is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you don't get enough engagement here, please consider providing a [mre] that others can copy an paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue, without depending on undeclared/private code or external libraries.  Right now this depends on apollo and some private code, which might be a barrier to getting a useful answer.